# Saving database as .mdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem that I want to save my database created in SQL Server as `.mdb` while it is saved as `.mdf` as default. So I don't find any way to do this please help me about it.

Comment: mdb is an access database file format. Are you saying you want to import a SQL server database to MDB (Access)?

Comment: Use the SSIS stuff in SSMS to export to JET or ACE while simultaneously questioning why you're using JET or ACE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

In the destination part choose Microsoft Access.